# How to track execution time of each step in an external current process using C#

Tags: c#

I know I can achieve this by using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` but how do I track the execution time for current process on which I am actually doing some actions. 
For example: An IE window in which I am opening Gmail and then login into it. So, I need to track how much time it took to load Gmail page and then again the load time for login; etc

Following code for reference:

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
// the code that you want to measure comes here
Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Well, I guess perhaps you could create an application that monitors web traffic and time the requests/responses that you are interested in. Not a simple task at all

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to do that through managed code.

Comment: @musefan Yes, if web time is all you are interested in. This doesn't take into consideration the render time of the browser and other possible actions taking place. Bottom line, OP can't do this without the external process' cooperation.

Comment: What does "external current process" in the title mean? That's a bit of an oxymoron.

Comment: your not explaining your self well... show  a code sample with sudo blocks/steps of code you want to time.

Comment: @Rotem - External Process meaning any other Process outside .net which I want to make action to. It could be web app, SAP app, any window activity like copying of files one folder to another, etc. but a Process on which my cursor is doing the actions hence 'Current'.